# Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm a little new to Tensor Flow and would like to understand why the following codes does not accept my input and how to resolve it. Prior to this, I was using `mode_save` but I have now converted this model to TFLite and would like to use it to predict the category of the inputted text.

I first load TFLite model and allocate tensors.

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="/model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

Then get input and output tensors.

```
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
```

Then tokenized my input data. I take my text and use texts_to_sequences which is just `tokenizer_from_json` in Tensorflow, then pad it as I do in my model training.
So my input is something like this...

```
[[144 122 557 136   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

This is the shape I would expect as I used the same one for my model training.

Now I just want to use tensor flow lite predict, however running the code below gives the following error:

```
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
text = 'We know what we are, but know not what we may be.'
seq = self.tokeniser.texts_to_sequences(text)
input_tensor= np.array(seq, dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_tensor)
```

**`Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 60 but expected 1 for dimension 1 of input 0.`**

Why?

This is what I have tried based on suggestions.....

```
output = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]  # Model has single output.
input = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]  # Model has single input.
input_data = tf.constant(padded_text, shape=[1, 1])
interpreter.set_tensor(input['index'], input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
print(interpreter.get_tensor(output['index']).shape)
```

which gives the following error:

> Eager execution of tf.constant with unsupported shape. Tensor [[144
> 122 557 136   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> 0   0   0   0   0   0]]

Comment: What does `print(interpreter.get_input_details())` return?

Comment: Try `seq = self.tokeniser.texts_to_sequences([text])`. I think the input should be list of texts.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur input shape ```[{'name': 'serving_default_embedding_input:0', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([1, 1], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([-1, -1], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
padded shape (1, 60)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input tensor is the wrong size. The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter#sample_execution) show that your input data should be of shape `1,1`:

```
input_data = tf.constant(1., shape=[1, 1])
interpreter.set_tensor(input['index'], input_data)
```

I suspect changing the line:

```
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_tensor)
```

to

```
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details['index'], input_tensor)
```

should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have updated my question with what happens with your solution and I still get an error